# Where to download Docusign Retrieve Application?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to look into the functionality of the retrieve application but did not find a link to download it. Please provide the link.

This is the [link](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/retrieve-quick-start-guide.pdf) I found for the Quick-start guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to reach out to DocuSign support on this matter, since it may or may not be included in your current DocuSign plan. Best to start with support.

Comment: thanks! They replied that it is available for purchase.